# What is the Wayland equivalent of xinput and synclient and ~/.xprofile?

Tags: synaptics, wayland, xinput

Ubuntu (21.10 now) wants us to use Wayland instead of X11 but how to do this in Wayland:

```
mac2011-linux% more ~/.xprofile
## emulate middle with double click
# xinput set-prop 12 353 1

## avoid spurious click to paste while scrolling
# xinput set-button-map 14 1 3 2
xinput list|grep pointer|tail -1|grep -o 'id=[0-9]*'|grep -o '[0-9]*'|xargs -i x
input set-button-map "{}" 1 3 2

# Synaptics touchpad settings
synclient LockedDrags=1
synclient HorizScrollDelta=-243
synclient TapButton3=2
```

?

More clearly, the above configures mouse buttons and Synaptics touchpad driver for my session.

Comment: It is done in `libinput`.

Comment: Installing the package `libinput-tools` and using the command `libinput` may work like `xinput`, but at least for me the biggest difference and disadvantage seems you need be *root* even just to see a *list of current input devices*. :-(

Comment: I just tried libinput list-devices without sudo. and it showed devices. 22.04